# Generator of the fundamental group of $ \mathbb RP^{2}$.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Take a closed hemisphere and identify the antipodal points on the equator ,we get $\mathbb RP^{2}$ and inside $ \mathbb RP^{2}$ we have copy of $ \mathbb RP^{1}$.So, what will be the induced map on fundamental group induced by inclusion?

I think ,if we know which homotopy class of loop in $\mathbb RP^{2}$ is generator,then some conclusion can be said easily.

Comment: Draw a line of longitude on the hemisphere.  Notice that since you're identifying points on the equator, this is actually a closed curve.  *That* is the generator of $\pi_1$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I might as well answer here to keep this from being bumped:

If you draw a line of longitude on the hemisphere, this is actually a closed curve due to the identification you make on the equator.  It will generate $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2$.

Comment: It seems intuitive to me, but how do you show that it is not path homotopic to the constant loop?

Comment: The easiest way, I think, is to note that it lifts to a non-closed curve in $S^2$.